# Is it possible to connect xamarin form to online database?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i have xamarin form and i want to connect it to the online database(postgresql)(digitalocean)

```
string ConnectionString = "Server=******; Port=5432;User Id=postgres; Password=******; Database=Accounting";
```

Do you have a documentation (step by step) for deployment? (xamarin.form(IOS and android)) database is postgresql

Comment: You should never expose your database servers directly to the outside. Let anything communicate through a service (f.i. REST API) with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Npgsql* library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) is compatible with .NET Core 3.0, .NET Standard 2.0/2.1 and .NET Framework 4.6.1, hence it should be no issue connecting to a Postgres database from your app - technically. *Npgsql* implements the ADO.NET pattern. E.g. to read users from a table `users` (**very** basic example), you could do the following:

```cs
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT id,name FROM users";
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var id = (long)reader["id"];
                var name = (string)reader["name"];

                // do something with the values
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Anyway, as stated in the comments, **it's bad practice and should be avoided**. Your database will be available publicly and anyone who's able to obtain the password would be able to mess with it. I have not verified this, but I assume that it should not be too hard to recover the password from the compiled app (at least on Android), which would be a severe security issue.

There may be constellations in which the implications would be slightly less severe, but I'd still avoid this at any rate.

You should really create a web service (does not nescessarily have to be a REST service) to access your Database. This service encapsulates all database access and allows fine-grained Authorization to access resources (e.g. with roles that have full access or read-only access) if required.

Comment: Do you have documentation on this ?

Comment: Documentation on what exactly?

Comment: i have online database already and i want to connect it to the xamarin.form,

Comment: but i dont know how, that is why i ask for documentation

Comment: Here is a tutorial on ASP.NET WebAPI (for HTTP webservices): https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-tutorials

Comment: Here is a blog post on how to run ASP.NET Apps on Linux, should be similar for WebAPI: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207336/discussion-between-paul-kertscher-and-kaito).